# WITH in Snowflake/SQL: Comparison to Temporary Tables

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, with-statement

Other than coder preference, is there any reason to use a series of WITH(SELECT . . . ) statements/clauses in Snowflake rather than create several temporary tables.  Are there performance or other issues that would lead one to prefer one method over the other?

Comment: Once the data is being processed on a warehouse, your performance will dramatically increase, so to write data back to storage and then read it for each temp table will likely affect your performance some, although some of that would be offset by warehouse cache, most likely.  So, it might depend on the complexity of what you are doing.  Have you tested and compared?

Comment: I'd add that with, WITH, you can inform the query engine of what you are doing and therefore it can be optimized. Whereas when you cross the statement boundary it's more hard for an engine to do optimizations.

In short the vasty majority of performance optimizations are done inside a single statement.

Answer (score 4):

I have some real world experience with this. We followed a hybrid approach in our ETLs

CTEs keeps results in memory, hence saves I/O cost while processing huge volume of data. Based on our experience processing an ETL involving 10 billion rows, CTE took 2 hours while table approach took 4.5 hours.But we should carefully choose our weapon, CTEs will not perform well in all scenarios. In the below scenarios, you must do some testing before using CTE

1. When your ETL query has more than 7-8 steps
2. Query is a combination of large and small tables
3. Volume of data is low and there is an opportunity to reuse the transformation logic

Please also remember CTEs cannot take advantage of meta data and hence row count estimations for joins and scans will be inaccurate and the optimizer will not be able to optimize the query path.